# Cocos Sharp With Xamarin.Forms PCL

Tags: xamarin.forms, cocossharp

While Creating **Cocos Sharp Project** With **PCL Xamarin.Forms** it gives the game layer in mid of screen how I can set it to full screen of mobile? I am mention below the steps which I am followed.

[Step 1 Creating Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNXBZ.png)

[Step 2 Output run on android device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BI13F.png)

Comment: I am asking the same question on Xamarin.Forms Forums. I mention its link below?   
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/103429/cocos-sharp-with-xamarin-forms-pcl/

Answer (score 0):

Are you planning to use Landscape or Portrait?
Did you change the ScreenOrientation?
[image: Change the ScreenOrientation]

If so, you may need to change the value of the desiredWidth and desiredHeight
[image: Desired Width and Height]